# Out Of Memory error in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I used the following code for showing dynamic images in ashx using c# asp, but am getting the error: "out of memory error"

This error show in VS and in IIS just show bottom not working:

[image]

Comment: Any idea on the size of Dynamic Picture that is being retrieved from the Database.

Comment: off topic, but you should wrap the SQL classes and streams in using-Blocks. Also you should use parameters when constructing queries to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why are you defining a SqlCommand and a SqlDataAdapter? The adapter doesn't seem to be used.